# Windows 10 clicking a file to open with the default program when that program is already open in the desktop you're already on?

Tags: windows-10, file-association, virtual-desktop, virtual-desktop-manager

Let's say I'm in Windows 10 on `Desktop 7`, and I find or download a PDF file and it opens in Adobe Acrobat.  If at that time Adobe Acrobat is already open on say `Desktop 1`, I'm jettisoned to `Desktop 1`.

Is there a way that I can stay on `Desktop 7` where I clicked the file, and the Adobe Acrobat window where it opens comes to me on `Desktop 7`, or appear on both `Desktop 1` and `Desktop 7`?

I know you can put windows like this on every single desktop, but that appears to require more concentration on such things than is really worth the effort.

Comment: Windows 10 virtual desktops is not as advanced as other desktop managers. That said, I don't think there is any desktop manager out there that does what you ask. If windows get snapped away from their original desktop, then what's the purpose of having virtual desktops anyway? I personally use a program that minimizes every program to the taskbar upon it becoming inactive, instead. Maybe that works for you too?

Comment: Awesome WM probably doesn’t work like that either, but it’s just easier to move windows around and move betweenness desktops using keyboard shortcuts.  Also if it opens it lights up that particular desktop instead of all that clicking and dragging in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

1. Open any PDF document
2. Open menu entry *Edit > Preferences*
3. Click *General* on the left of the window that opens
4. Uncheck the option of "Open documents as new tabs in the same window (requires restart)"
5. Restart Adobe Acrobat